# Does the tables join order affect the query result?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join

There are three tables,t1,t2,t3.Every table has a field f. Are these pairs of sqls the same?

```
1.select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join t2 on t1.f =t2.f left join t3 on t1.f = t3.f

select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join t3 on t1.f =t3.f left join t2 on t1.f = t2.f

2.select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join t2 on t1.f =t2.f inner join t3 on t1.f = t3.f

select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 inner join t3 on t1.f =t3.f left join t2 on t1.f = t2.f

3.select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join t2 on t1.f =t2.f right join t3 on t1.f = t3.f

select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 right join t3 on t1.f =t3.f left join t2 on t1.f = t2.f

4.select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join t2 on t1.f =t2.f full join t3 on t1.f = t3.f

select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 full join t3 on t1.f =t3.f left join t2 on t1.f = t2.f

5.select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join t2 on t1.f =t2.f left join t3 on t2.f = t3.f

select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1 left join (t2 left join t3 on t2.f = t3.f) on t1.f =t2.f
```

...Keep any two tables of three tables have the same join and same join fields. Are the query results same? How to understand it easily?

I want to know how to prove it. When I used oracle (+) to join table, I found (+) don't show the table join order.if the results are different, What is the oracle default order?

I know t1 left join t2 is different from t2 left join t1, for it convert to (+) is differnt sql. Above sql, you convert it to (+) are same.

For example the last pair of sqls can convert to select t1.f,t2.f,t3.f from t1,t2,t3 where t1(+)=t2 and t2(+)=t3, as in the where clause no order.And in sql join's wiki, the explicit join and implicit join are equal. So if the result of pairs of sqls was different, it would be contradiction.

Comment: Just try it out, and you'll see.

Comment: I insert some data, the results are same.But maybe it's only because my data reason. I want to know how to prove it. When I used oracle (+) to join table, I found (+) don't show the table join order.if the results are different, What is the oracle default order?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best knowledge:

A left join B 
~ A ∪ (A ∩ B)
~ A

A right join B 
~ (A ∩ B) ∪ B
~ B

A full join B
~ A ∪ B

A inner join B
~ A ∩ B

```
#1
t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ t3)                         t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ t2)
~ t1                                   ~ t1 

#2
t1 ∩ t3                                (t1 ∩ t3) ∪ (t1 ∩ t3 ∩ t2) 
~ t1 ∩ t3                              ~ t1 ∩ t3 

#3
(t1 ∩ t3 ) ∪ t3                        t3 ∪ (t1 ∩ t3 ∩ t2)
~ t3                                   ~ t3

#4
t1 ∪ t3                                (t1 ∪ t3) ∪ (t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ t2))
~ t1 ∪ t3                              ~ t1 ∪ t3

#5
(t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ t2)) ∪ (t1 ∩ t2 ∩ t3)      t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ (t2 ∪ (t2 ∩ t3)))
~ t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ t2 ∩ t3)                  ~ t1 ∪ (t1 ∩ t2)
~ t1                                   ~ t1
```

I tried to make it shorter even for the first expression to void confusion. For #5 I made it little longer to be clearer. Let me know if you wanna see the complete expanded expression.

Answer (score 0):

In left join the result of

```
from  t1  left join t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f2
```

could be different from

```
from  t2  left join t1 on t1.f1 = t2.f2
```

Try think a column with null value if the are in t1 in the first case don't select rows  in t2 in the  second  case the same column produce row with null value in these columns ..

For inner join naturally there aren't difference ..

Answer (score 0):

### No for INNER joins

Not only the result are the same bu the engine of the DBMS ill optmize the query and mostly times the query plan (and therefore the perfomance) ill be the same.
**There are no default order**. The DBMS will most likely join the tables following some internal optmization. For example it can try to iterate over the smaller (with less rows) tables first.

### Yes for OUTER JOINS

See this case: You got tables A, B and C and you query A and **LEFT JOIN** B and C.

```
create table A 
(
   idA int
  ,idB int
  ,idC int
)

create table B 
(
   idA int
  ,idB int
  ,idC int
)

create table C 
(
   idA int
  ,idB int
  ,idC int
)

insert into A values
(1,1,null),(2,2,null)

insert into B values
(1,1,null),(2,2,null)
```

Now There are lots of rows in A and for each row in A there are one row in B but C in empty. You ill Got all rows in A x B.
Now try to left join C before B...

```
select *
from A
left join B on B.idB = A.idB
left join C on C.idC = B.idC


select *
from A
left join C on C.idC = A.idC
left join B on B.idB = C.idB
```

... the results differ!

```
idA         idB         idC         idA         idB         idC         idA         idB         idC
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           NULL        1           1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2           2           NULL        2           2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL

(2 row(s) affected)

idA         idB         idC         idA         idB         idC         idA         idB         idC
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
2           2           NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Also as a rule of thumb if you mix outter and inners joins put the inner joins first because any join after a outter join ill be a *defacto* outter join even if you intent to write a inner join.

OP also asks about (+) ... implict join I guess. The difference between explicit and implicit joins is **joins** clauses are processed before **where** clauses.

**Edit**

As @Michael Broughton commented if there are not join chain then order don't matter.

Comment: In most of the examples, however, he is outer joining both B and C to A - not chaining the joins A->B->C vs A->C->B. If both B and C are outer joined directly to A the results should be the same.